# Need to get local computername into MS Flow for Sharepoint

Tags: flow

Help please.  I have trawled the net looking for an answer to no avail.   All I want to do is capture the %computername% (local workstation name) while running a flow from Sharepoint as the output i create needs this info to be of any use to us.  Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.
The flow will be running on a cloud server with no knowledge or connection to the local workstations, so there is no way of capturing this.

You will have to find another way to initiate the flow, probably with something installed on every computer as a browser does not have access to this kind of information anyways.

Comment: OK so can i lookup the asset number using userID from List A against List B - basically a vlookup - and if yes,  how can I use that info in a Flow?

Comment: You would use the **Get items** action and then filter the items. Then you would use the **Get item** to retrieve the item details for each returned item.